# Reading server-side CSV file

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I am trying to import CSV data from a CSV file using Javascript. I wrote the code and I don't know what the problem is. When I upload the HTML page to my website it does not work and the script kinda crashes. I tried multiple ways but none worked. Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "files/testfile.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
      html: csv
    },
    success: function(data) {
      processData(data);
    }
  });
});

function processData(allText) {
  var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
  var lines = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
    if (data.length == headers.length) {

      var tarr = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        tarr.push(headers[j] + ":" + data[j]);
      }
      lines.push(tarr);
    }
  }
  alert(lines);
}
```

Help is much appreciated

Comment: If you are simply reading the .csv file which is already located on your server, you should use GET instead of POST.  Also, why are you sending data to the file and what is the csv variable?  I cannot see it declared anywhere.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also @HaukurHaf has pointed out some odd points in your code which you should check.

Comment: @HaukurHaf where do  you see sending data to the CSV file, and what do you mean by csv variable? , if you see anything wrong can you put the right way? thank you

Comment: These lines here: 
data: {
      html: csv
    },

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "files/testfile.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      processData(data); //define your own function
    }
  });
});
```

If it's still not working, check your browser console for errors.  You might also try putting some console.log() lines in there to see what's going on.

Comment: the error is: Failed to load resourcehttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.jsthe server responded with a status of 404 (OK)

Comment: Well If you try to open this file in your browser, it does not exist.  Use this path instead: //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js

Comment: I found the problem: I changed 1.12.3 to 1.12.0 and https to http and it worked :) , Thanks alot for your help